# How to search from top xxx rows in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a database with over 1 million records, I want to find a value in this database, but I know that this value is found somewhere in the top 1000 records.

```
List<string> onHoldOrderslist = 
     orderList.Where(m => (m.customerId == item.customerId)
                          && (m.Marketplace == Market.US) 
                          && (m.OrderStatus == "onHold"))
              .Select(s => s.OrderId)
              .ToList();
```

In the code, I do not want to search the whole `orderList` database table, just the top xxx records.

My questions are:

1. How is it done with linq? I couldn't find any example!
2. Does it enhance the query performance?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
List<string> onHoldOrderslist = orderList.Where(m => (m.customerId == item.customerId) && (m.Marketplace == Market.US) && (m.OrderStatus == "onHold"))
.OrderBy(x => x.WhateverMakesSense)
.Take(1000)
.Select(s => s.OrderId)
.ToList();
```

Please note that ordering is important as otherwise you may get random 1000 elements...

Comment: Sorting 1M records will consume time, if OP is sure about the statement which he mentioned in his question, then why should we put more efforts to order 1M records.. correct me if I am worng

Comment: Typically such statements go to the database, where no precise ordering is given...

Comment: Why do i need to sort it? it's already sorted every time i save changes (by datetime), that's how i know my value is in the top xxx rows.

Answer (score 0):

Given you say this is "a record" and you are only returning one, don't worry about the fact that it's in the top 1000 (and top doesn't even mean anything unless you specify an order). Using `Take(1000)` after the where clause will do nothing as there is only one record anyway. All you need is an index, in this case on `customerId`, `Marketplace`, and `OrderStatus`.

Comment: That's right. If the database is set up properly, it should have indices on important columns and deliver results instantly. As of question two: No, I am quite sure it does not enhance the performance.

Comment: Quote: (and top doesn't even mean anything unless you specify an order) , i always sort my table before saving the changes, so it's sorted by datetime, What if i Take(1000) and do my search on this new list?

Comment: Your table is not sorted in the order you save changes. It is ordered on disk according to the clustered index (for all relational DBs I know of). Query results can be returned in any order if no OrderBy is specified. So Take(1000) and searching on the new list will work if and only if the results are returned in the order you wrote them - and there's no guarantee that will be the case without specifying an OrderBy.